# SQL Server linked server error "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions."

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have a linked server (SQL Server 14.0.1000.169). The local server (SQL Server 10.0.1600) receives data in short periods of time, around 1 new row per minute, into `Table46`. I need to pass some of the information of this new row to the linked server, so I created a trigger in the local server for this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER New_Event 
ON  dbo.Table46 FOR INSERT AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[TableEvents]
    SELECT    i.[046_ID] AS [id]
            , NP.NoPart + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), T41.[041_No]) AS [name]
            , DATEADD(MINUTE, -1 * i.[046_ExeTime], i.[046_DateTime]) AS [eventstart]
            , i.[046_DateTime] AS [eventend]
            , i.[046_IDRes] AS [resource_id]
            , i.[046_ExeTime] AS [execution]
            , ISNULL(MIN(T48.[048_MachTime]), 0) AS [same]
            , ISNULL(MIN(T48_1.[048_MachTime]), 0) AS [all]
            , i.[046_Pallet] AS [pallet]
    FROM inserted AS i
        INNER JOIN Table41 AS T41
            ON i.[046_IDOp] = T41.[041_IDOp]
        INNER JOIN NoParts AS NP
            ON T41.[041_IDNoPart] = NP.Autonumber
        INNER JOIN Table48 AS T48
            ON i.[046_IDRes] = T48.[048_IDRes]
            AND i.[046_IDOp] = T48.[048_IDOp]
        INNER JOIN Table48 AS T48_1
            ON i.[046_IDOp] = T48_1.[048_IDOp]
    GROUP BY i.[046_ID], NP.NoPart, T41.[041_No], i.[046_MachTime], 
            i.[046_DateTime], i.[046_IDRes], i.[046_ExeTime], i.[046_Pallet];
END;
```

The original query after the `INSERT INTO` works, I just changed `Table46` for the `inserted` virtual table because of the trigger.

**Edit 1:**

If I add a new row manually to `Table46` I get the following error (already started MSDTC service):

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "[LinkedServer]" returned message "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.".
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure New_Event, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 15]
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "[LinkedServer]" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

**Edit 2:**

I have followed [these instructions](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/19813/linked-server-error-the-partner-transaction-manage.html) and also allowed MSDTC inbound rules in the Firewall of both servers but now if I try to add the row the query takes a lot of time executing, it hasn't finished yet. The same is happening with a `SELECT` query to `Table46`.

What are other ways to insert in the remote server whenever `Table46` receives a new row, if triggers don't work?

Comment: Good lord. 10.0.1600 is 2008 RTM. No only are you using a completely unsupported version of sql server you are using the very first release of that version. Ignoring the fragility of this approach to replication, triggers work quite well. You will need to provide more context. What "doesn't work"? How do you test this?

Comment: @SMor After executing the `CREATE TRIGGER`, not only it doesn't fire, but also `Table46` stops saving the new rows.

Comment: How do you know the trigger does not fire? If the `INSERT` inside the trigger fails the insert to `Table46` fails as well. What happens when you insert a record to `Table46` what happens? Do you get an error? Do you get a success but nothing is saved? How many records does SQL server say were affected?

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis I have edited the question

Comment: The insert to `Table46` and the insert to the linked server occur in the same (distributed) transaction. When doing the inserts separately you are doing it on two separate (local) transactions. You need to configure your SQL servers to be able to use distributed transactions. (as a mater of fact the error message pretty musch says it all)

Comment: @SMor raises a very big point in their original comment.  14.0.1000.169 is the RTM version of 2017 as well. What do you have against patching? You're not only using an unsupported version of SQL Server, you're using two that *have* multiple **known** security flaws.

Comment: Regarding performance: distributed transactions are slower since they have to coordinate the servers and only commit the cahnges once both servers agree. See my other suggestion about SQL Broker. I've successfully implemented similar scenarions with SQL Broker between server across the globe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment you need to configure MSDTC to enable distributed transactions between the two linked SQL servers.

If you don't want to do that, then you can use a trigger on the source table to save the required data in a 'queue' table. Then you can have a separate application poll the queue table, fetch data and insert them on the linked server on separate connections (and thus separate transactions). This method may seem suboptimal but does have one advantage: if the linked server is unavailable or slow the source server continues to work at full speed and no data is ever lost.

One way to implement the second approach is to use SQL Server broker. In the trigger send the necessary data to a message queue. On the receiving (linked) server process the messages and insert the data in `TableEvents`. SQL Server Broker ensures transactional integrity all the way without the use of MSDTC between the two servers while decoupling the two servers. Note that the servers no longer need to be linked anymore (unless you need them linked for some other reason)

Comment: I will look the second approach up because the MSDTC is bothering me a lot, as I say in the second edit in the question.

Comment: SQL Server Broker has somewhat steep learning curve and configuration initially may seem over complicated. But once you get everything ironed out, there is no going back.

Comment: thanks, I got Service Broker to work, for now it's between 2 servers in the same network, but I hope that it will still work when the remote server is up. I followed this tutorial: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/building-a-distributed-service-broker-application